# component doesn't get loaded again one more time

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I have the following routes in one of my modules .

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    DriverHomeComponent,
    DriverNavbarComponent,
    DriverProfileComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      { 
        path: 'driver/cabinet', 
        component: DriverHomeComponent,

      },
      {
        path: 'driver/cabinet/profile',
        component: DriverProfileComponent
      }
    ])
  ],


  exports:[
    DriverNavbarComponent
  ]
})
export class DriverModule { }
```

When I go to `driver/cabinet  DriverHomeComponent` successfully gets loaded, then i click the button which takes me to `driver/cabinet/profile` and this loads `DriverProfileComponent`. Now I click backwards , which takes me to `driver/cabinet` again. now when I click the button again, it doesn't take me to `driver/cabinet/profile` again and even url doesn't change and stay as `driver/cabinet` .

Why doesn't it show the contents of `DriverProfileComponent` of the second time I want to visit this? I don't have http calls or something, just simple plain html in `DriverProfileComponent` .

```
<ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="false" *ngFor="let p of driverNavBarComponents">
    <ion-item [routerDirection]="p.direction" [routerLink]="[p.url]" color="primary">
      <ion-icon slot="start" [name]="p.icon"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>
        {{p.title}}
      </ion-label>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-menu-toggle>
```

Comment: Please post the code of your `DriverProfileComponent`

Comment: Consider turning on route tracing. That prints routing information into the console to help you better debug routing issues. Add `{ enableTracing: true}` as the second argument to the `.forChild([...], { enableTracing: true})`

Comment: You don't have any error in console ?

Comment: No error. I tried enable tracing but it prints so much info, don't even know how to debug. all seems fine.

Comment: Focus on the last set of data ... the time it doesn't work. Look for the set for that particular navigation focusing on: NavigationStart and NavigationEnd. If the route isn't routing to the correct place, the NavigationEnd should show where it is routing to. You can then follow the events back to see where it went wrong.

Comment: Also, please add the code you are using to activate the route. Are you using a router link? Or `.navigate` in the code? What does that syntax look like?

Comment: @NikaKhurashvil If you have somewhere in your app `path: '**'`. Searching for it and removing for testing might be helpful. If path doesn't match, Angular gives an error that might help to understand what is wrong.

Comment: Maybe consider creating a StackBlitz for us.

Comment: I use routerlink . i will add that router link code.